# How can I find if some commit is included in branch?

Tags: svn, branch

During development we commit into trunk, when time comes we create branch to be tested separately and further turned into tag.

My question is: is there a simple way to find out whether some commit, that we made into trunk some some days ago, is inside our branch?

Different flavour of this question: how can I find out when the branch was created?

(In other words, my branch can miss some commit if it was done after the branch was created. I want to ensure that commit is inside branch. One way to check this is probably to make a --dry-run merge for all revisions)

Comment: If (revisionOfBranchCreation > revisionInQuestionIntrunk) Then Yes Else check the mergeinfo of the branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to find out whether some commit, that we made into trunk some some days ago, is inside our branch?

This could be asking for two different things:

- You made a change to both trunk and the branch in the same commit.

  - A `svn log -v` will show you this information.
  - You could also do a `svn log --xml` on both the trunk and branch. Store the revisions in a hash for the branch, and then when you parse the output of the trunk, you can see if there is a duplicate revision on the branch.
- You did a merge, so the changes in a particular revision in trunk is in your branch. in this case, you could look at the `svn:mergeinfo` property on the branch which will show you what truck revisions have been merged into the branch. A `svn plist -v -R svn:mergeinfo` will find all `svn:mergeinfo` properties on any files or directories in the entire directory tree and show you which revisions were merged in.

> Different flavour of this question: how can I find out when the branch was created?

To find out when a branch was created:

```
 svn log -v --stop-on-copy -r1:HEAD /usr/of/branch | head
```

This will show all revisions on the branch from lowest to highest, so it will show you the first revision on that branch. The `head` limits the output. You shouldn't need more than 10 lines. The `-v` flag will show what revision was copied and from what source.

The output will look something like this:

```
r160214 | dweintraub | 2013-04-23 13:41:43 -0400 (Tue, 23 Apr 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/4.8 (from /trunk:160213)

Creating a release branch for 4.8 release
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The 4.8 branch was created on April 23, 2013 by me from revision 160213 of trunk.

Comment: David, regarding the first question: my case is even easier: I was working with trunk, then made a branch from it via svn copy, then time has passed and I have forgotten whether some precious commit is inside that branch, or it is left in trunk because it was made after the branching. Its not about changing both trunk and branch, and not about merging. How can I test it?

Comment: @KutaBeach Then, the second part of the answer will help. This will establish when the branch was made. For example, you can see that the 4.8 branch was made from revision 160213 of trunk. If your change was committed to turn before revision 160213, you know it's on the branch. If it was after revision 160213 on trunk, you know it was after the branch.

Answer (score 1):

`svn log -q --stop-on-copy /URL/OF/BRANCH`

last revision in list is first revision of branch

Comment: Thanks, Lazy Badger! Looks like there are 2 points: numbers of revisions committed to branch BEFORE creating this branch (i.e. committed to trunk) remain the same. So we can check for some revision via svn log -r REV_NUMBER. But revisions that were merged into already created branch go in one new commit. Thus, we cannot find out whether some commit from trunk is included in our branch in this case. Am I right?

Comment: @KutaBeach - starting point and revisions-list are different questions. Check `svn:mergeinfo` property in the root of branch in order to get merged into branch revisions from other subtrees